# underscorejs map with jquery

Tags: jquery, functional-programming, underscore.js

I am trying to use underscorejs contribe (http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore-contrib/) and jQuery to construct objects. My code looks like this

```
1.  var rightMap = _.rcurry2(_.map);
2.  var tabKeys = ['tab1', 'tab2', 'tab3', 'tab4'],
3.      rootElements = _.pipeline(
4.                         rightMap(function(k){return '#' + k;}),
5.                         rightMap(function(k){return $(k);})  //Here is what confused me
6.                     )(tabKeys);
//expected result: [$('#tab1'), $('#tab2'), $('#tab3'),$('#tab4')];
```

this code works as expected. However, I am not happy with line 5. I wanted to replace line 5 with

```
  rightmap($)
```

this attempt broke the code. Only $('#tab1') was created. I was getting

```
  [$('#tab1'), [], [],[]];
```

as the result. I am wondering what is the differences between theses two pieces of code.

Thanks.

**Update: I have added the link to the library I am using.**

Update: add jsfiddle result 
http://jsfiddle.net/qbzuduom/1/   is the working situation
http://jsfiddle.net/qbzuduom/2/   is the one with problem.

please press f12 in your browser and look at the console to see the difference.

What made the difference in the code?

**Update:** Thanks to the help from @muistooshort, I was able to generate the desired solution, and gained more understanding of the jquery $ function. 
Please check http://jsfiddle.net/qbzuduom/6/ for the updated demo

Comment: What is `_.rcurry2`? What is `_.pipeline`? Underscore has neither of these. Lodash doesn't have them either.

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/qbzuduom/

Comment: the one you Posted is the working one, but my question is about modifying and stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you misunderstand how `_.rcurry2` works or how `_.map` works or possibly both.

From the fine [`_.rcurry2` manual](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore-contrib/#rcurry2):

> **Signature:** `_.rcurry2(func:Function)`
>
> Returns a curried version of `fund` where a maxium of two arguments are processed from right to left.

This, more or less, modifies how the arguments to `_.map` are handled so that instead of `_.map(a, b)` you can say `rightMap(b)(a)`. Note that `_.rcurry2` has nothing at all to do with how `_.map` calls its function.

Then for [`_.map` we have](http://underscorejs.org/#map):

> **map** `_.map(list, iteratee, [context])`
>
> Produces a new array of values by mapping each value in **list** through a transformation function (**iteratee**). If **list** is a JavaScript object, **iteratee**'s arguments will be `(value, key, list)`.

The `_.map` documentation leaves something very important out: it doesn't tell you what the `iteratee` arguments will be when `list` is an array, it only tells you want they'll be when `list` is an object. When you `_.map` an array, the iterator function is called as:

```
iteratee(list[i], i, list)
```

Take note of that second argument, that's where all your problems come from.

If we combine the above, we see that this:

```
rightMap($)
```

is the same as saying:

```
rightMap(function(k, i, list) { return $(k, i, list) })
```

The [`$` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) does understand more than one argument so that `i` will be treated as a "context":

```
Internally, selector context is implemented with the `.find()` method, so  `$( "span", this )` is equivalent to  `$( this ).find( "span" )`.
```

and that gives us:

```
rightMap(function(k, i, list) { return $(i).find(k) })
```

which won't find anything useful. I'm guessing that jQuery is doing a simple `if(context)` check so the `i === 0` case works because `0` is falsey.

In any case, you can't pass `$` like that, you need to manually restrict the arguments it gets with something like:

```
var oneDollar = function() { $(arguments[0]) }
```

and `rightMap(oneDollar)` later on:

```
var rootElements = _.pipeline(
    rightMap(function(k) { return '#' + k }),
    rightMap(oneDollar)
)(tabKeys);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/f5uvaa4m/

The second argument to `$` doesn't seem to be widely used these days so I'm not surprised that you missed it.

Comment: thanks for this very detailed answer. I will double check the _.map for array implementation and the second parameter for $ function unknown to me too.

Comment: A quick `_(['a','b']).map(function() { console.log(arguments) })` might be worth a look too.

Comment: turns out the second parameter, context for $ function is the problem. I have created a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/qbzuduom/6/ and it worked the way I want.